# Записать отчет в таблице?

Tags: mysql

Я сейчас создаю БД. Вопрос
 Есть ли смысл создать таблицу для отчетов? Отчет создается каждый месяц. 
Понимаю можно выбрать несколько таблиц, но это замедлить работу базы. Для ускорения можно создать отдельную таблицу?

Я просто хочу узнать совет или мнение более опытных программистов, чем я.

Comment: Можно создать таблицу сформированных отчётов (только данные, само собой). Это если нужна версионка (поднять несколько отчётов на один и тот же кол времени, но с "допиленными" данными). Если же версионка не нужна, то раз в месяц - это частота, при которой даже не надо думать о производительности.

Comment: Уточните входные данные. По опыту, сначала нужен простенький отчет. Его можно строить в режиме реального времени. Потом "а давайте в него добавим ...". Потом отчет нужен раз в неделю. Потом персональный - каждому департаменту / директору свой, им "чужие данные" не нужны. Отчет начинает строиться около часа. А дайте сделаем задание, пусть ночью строится... Так что смотрите, какая будет эволюция. Для профессиональных отчетов уже есть спец решения типа Power BI. @see также OLAP